# Disable Secondary Receiver on PayPal Adaptive

Tags: paypal, chained-payments

I am setting up a system that takes payments through PayPal. I'm using adaptive chained payments so I can charge a transaction fee to my users on free accounts, but it seems as though adaptive MAKEs you have a secondary receiver and makes the secondary have to have a value greater than zero sent to them. Is there a way to disable and only pay the main user if I don't want to charge a transaction fee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pay API does not force a secondary receiver unless you've set the primary receiver flag for the first one to true.  All you need to do is create a Pay API request with a single receiver that is NOT set as a primary receiver.